How to edit or modify the Data folder on Android 14 (Xiaomi 14T)?
I know it sounds like a recurring topic, but I would really like to know how to modify the contents of the Data folder in Android 14. I am currently using a Xiaomi 14T that has HyperOS (1.0.8.0.UNEMIXM) and Android 14 UP1A.231005.007.
I have used tools like Shizuku and they have not worked for me, nor can I get that menu to appear to give permissions to a certain file explorer, since the Data folder simply does not appear. For example, I have used Super File Manager Explorer, which allows me to see the Data folder, and all the content of the applications but it does not let me edit, delete or add anything. I do not want to become an expert in programming, because I am not, therefore I will not try to move or do strange processes that can damage my device, also I do not want to Root it because I have no idea how to do it, nor because of the issue of updating it manually and that method is known to leave smartphones in a loop, so Root is not an option.
Does anyone know of a safe way to edit the data folder? I'm not very experienced in this area, but I thought of deleting the default "Files" app on the device, but I'm sure that would cause more than one problem. As I said, Shizuku didn't work for me with either the wireless or wired method.

Please tell us the exact path of the "the Data folder" you are talking about (the full Linux path in the file-system). Android has multiple places where "data folders" are stored each with different permissions.
